# How do I animate UICollectionView insert with Swift?

Tags: swift, animation, uicollectionview

I have tried it with collectionView.reloadData(), but that didn't really work out. What do I do?

Comment: Somehow, you should use [insertItems(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618097-insertitems) method.

Because of there is no code snippet, i.e it is a generic question, I suggest to check [this article](http://rshankar.com/uicollectionview-demo-in-swift/) -*Insert Cell* section- to check how you can play with it.

Comment: Your comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your collectionview has only one section try:

```
self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                let indexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: 0...0)
                self.collectionView.reloadSections(indexSet)
            }, completion: nil)
```

As seen on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42001389/4455570

Answer (score -1):

reloadData does not alter layout nor animates.
You have to change position of items, so for example:

```
func shuffleTwoCells(srcIndex index1: Int, destIndex index2: Int) {
    let firstIndexPath  = IndexPath(row: Int(index1), section: 0)
    let secondIndexPath = IndexPath(row: Int(index2), section: 0)
    self.collectionView?.moveItem(at: firstIndexPath, to: secondIndexPath)
}
```

Comment: But that is for swapping two, not inserting a new one, is it?