# Reload section method in swift 3?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I have code written in objective c.I want to convert this code into the swift3 code.

```
[_expandableTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:gestureRecognizer.view.tag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

After converting using online tool it gave me below code but it does not work

```
expandableTableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(index: gestureRecognizer.view!.tag), with: .automatic)
```

Please tell me how to do it ?

Comment: "does not work" means... ? what does the error says?

Answer (score 50):

Reload Section in **Swift 3.0**

> i.e Reloading 0th section to 0th Section, Because tableview has
> default one section that index is 0.

```
//let myRange: ClosedRange = 0...0

self.tableViewPostComments.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0...0), with: UITableViewRowAnimation.top)
```

**For Swift 4**

```
self.tableViewPostComments.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0...0), with: UITableView.RowAnimation.top)
```

**For Swift 5**

> In Swift 5 you can use this short & simple line.

```
self.tableViewPostComments.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0...0), with: .top)
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, it helps me.

Answer (score 36):

do like in **swift3** for more information see [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66881)

```
expandableTableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: gestureRecognizer.view!.tag), with: .automatic)
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that after the conversion `NSIndexSet` became `IndexSet`. [IndexSet](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexset) is the Swift overlay to the Foundation framework for [NSIndexSet](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsindexset):

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the IndexSet
>   structure, which bridges to the NSIndexSet class and its mutable
>   subclass, NSMutableIndexSet. The IndexSet value type offers the same
>   functionality as the NSIndexSet reference type, and the two can be
>   used interchangeably in Swift code that interacts with Objective-C
>   APIs. This behavior is similar to how Swift bridges standard string,
>   numeric, and collection types to their corresponding Foundation
>   classes.

If you checked the description of `reloadSections` method signature, you will note that it is:

> reloadSections(_ sections: IndexSet, with animation:
>   UITableViewRowAnimation

`sections` parameter is `IndexSet` but NOT `NSIndexSet` anymore.

So, what you could do is:

```
_expandableTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: gestureRecognizer.view.tag) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
```

OR I prefer to add IndexSet without even using the `as IndexSet`:

```
_expandableTableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: gestureRecognizer.view!.tag), with: .automatic)
```

Comment: confused. Does this mean you can't just do: `_expandableTableView.reloadSections([0]), with: .automatic)` <-- This should reload only section `0`